# Building 3rd party linux kernel modules: changes with kernels after 4.9?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, debian-based

I've been building my own kernels on Ubuntu for years, using `make-kpkg` from the kernel-package package. All I had to do after installing the linux-image and linux-headers packages was to correct the /lib/modules/4.x.y/{source,build} symlinks so they pointed to the /usr/src/linux-headers-4.x.y directory instead of to the source tree (which I'd trash because HUGE).

Last kernel I did this with was 4.9.30 (with Con Kolivas's patches). Doing the same with 4.15.7 and 4.14.23 works for some 3rd party modules (for instance, ZFS) but not with others, like the driver for the RTL8812au WIFI adapter (or even the host kernel extensions from VirtualBox 5.2.8-121009~Ubuntu~trusty). There, I'm seeing this:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.14.23-ck1-mainline-core2-rjvb/build M=/path/to/rtl8812au_rtl8821au-git  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.23-ck1-mainline-core2-rjvb'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
        echo >&2;                                                       \
        echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
        echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
        echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
        echo >&2 ;                                                      \
        /bin/false)
mkdir -p /path/to/rtl8812au_rtl8821au-git/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/bertin/work/src/Scratch/RTL881x/rtl8812au_rtl8821au-git/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/path/to/rtl8812au_rtl8821au-git
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/path/to/rtl8812au_rtl8821au-git/core/rtw_io.o', needed by `/path/to/rtl8812au_rtl8821au-git/8812au.o'. Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/path/to/rtl8812au_rtl8821au-git] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.23-ck1-mainline-core2-rjvb'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

This happens with the latest kernel-package version I could find on launchpad.

Two explanations (both of which are probably not wrong):
1. the tree installed in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.1x.y* is somehow incomplete
2. something has to be changed in the 3rd party extension module

I'd go with 2) were it not for the fact that apparently at least one of the various 8812au driver repos builds just fine against 4.14 and 4.15, and I must assume that this holds too for VirtualBox. (There are some reports of the error I'm seeing but in an older version, supposedly fixed in 5.2.7 .)

Any idea what is being excluded from the /usr/src/linux-headers-4.1x.y directory? Or what would need to be changed in the module build system?
I'd really love to get it to work again because even clean full kernel source tree is almost 10x bigger...

The RTL 8812au driver source I'm working with: github.com/RJVB/rtl8812au_rtl8821au .